# Should questions be marked with contraindicated tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Should a question be marked with a tag such as [database-mirroring](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database-mirroring) if the OP identifies that mirroring doesn't apply?

For reference, see [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52582/approaches-for-real-time-copy-of-database-on-same-sql-server-instance) which has 3 tags about tech the OP has identified that wouldn't be an answer to his problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help), under [Tagging](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), it states:

> What are tags, and how should I use them?
>
> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.

With this in mind, I would say in general contraindicated tags should be avoided, and perhaps even removed from affected questions.

Comment: For that specific question I actually removed the tag because I really felt it wasn't needed. So your answer makes sense :-).